# bixby: Audio is playing message twice while on selection page (simulator)

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

My capsule was working good and still working good if used on `BixbyStudio-6.8.1-r19f.7483-win` but after the latest update, my capsule is reading message twice on selection page. My message is

> Please select one of the following

it is showing proper on the screen but while reading, it is reading like

> Please select one of the following ... press back if you want to pick
>   up where you left off ... Please select one of the following

The message "press back if you want to pick up where you left off" keep changing in every hit. Sometimes it says

> what you you like to do next

Every other message is good but this is happening on selection page.
My selection code is

```
input-view {
    match: FoodChoiceResult (this)

    render {
       if (size(this.multiple_choice)>0){
          selection-of (this) {
             navigation-mode {
               read-many {
                  page-size (3)
                     page-content{
                        underflow-statement (This is the final set)
                        item-selection-question (Please select one of the following)
                        overflow-statement (That's all I have)
                     }
                  }
               }
               has-details (false)
               where-each (item) {
                  layout-macro (food-type-summary) {
                     param (singleFoodItem) {
                       expression (item)
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
     }
  }
```

please suggest if this is issue from end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this one is on us.

IDE simulator has this issue. There is a bug. Our IDE engineers are working toward a solution.

Meanwhile on-device testing should be ok, voice output should only speak once and with no additional content.

Sorry about the inconvenience. 
I will post updates regarding this issue here.

=== 
IDE release [version 6.14.0](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/release-notes/bixby-studio.6-14-0) should fix this issue, please verify.

Comment: Thanks for the update... Also when I am testing my capsule on simulator everything is fine but while loading revision id on mobile device there is some bug.... When I select the option it is saying I ran into problem but same thing is working fine on simulator

Comment: @RahulGupta I had an idea what the on-device issue you described is. there is unfortunately an issue with API calls on-device (well, due to the marketplace lunch update). The fix will (hopefully) in the next update. Sorry, seems now although IDE voice output sounds wired, it is the only way to test in your case.

Comment: New version has been released but the issues remain. Please clarify. Also, after today's update, I changed my capsule version as previous has version compatibility issue but couldn't be able to submit it for review. I cancelled the previous version, which was under review and then tried to submit the new one but it is showing "The capsule already has a version under review".

Comment: Yesterday's release does not include the fix for this issue. If I remember correctly, you are the developer of eventseeker. In that case, your submission is fine and requires no re-submission.

Comment: ok.. thanks. But when i loaded my previous revision id into my mobile device or on simulator, it was giving my version compatibility issue.

Comment: You need a new private submission in order to do on-device testing after the SDK change yesterday noon. But, no worry about the public submission we are reviewing. BTW, today's IDE release should fix the repeated dialog issue. I updated my answer.

Comment: Now after fix, do I need to resubmit or previous one will work?

Comment: No, you don't need to resubmit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196552/discussion-between-rahul-gupta-and-bixbydevsupport-tokonyan).